# jQuery Ajaxcall crashing all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a (heavy) function that fetches some data from php/sql and then render it in html. When I load the page for the first time I call this function and everything is fine. When I click on a button I call this function also after an successfull other ajax call, but then my browsers freezes and crashes. I get in Firefox and Chrome an error (page unresponsive).

Here the (heavy)function:

```
function getMinerAttributesByType(type) {
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "/app/ajax/DataminerAjax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout : 8000,
        data    : {getMinerAttributesByType:type}
    }).success(function(json){
        $tableConfigured = $("#keywordsgroupsConf tbody");
        $tableConfigured.html("");
        $tableUnconfigured = $("#keywordsgroups tbody");
        $tableUnconfigured.html("");
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
            var $table;
            if (value.configured == 0) {
                $table = $tableUnconfigured;
            } else {
                $table = $tableConfigured;
            }
            $table.append('<tr>' +
                          '<td>' + value.name + '</td>' +
                          '<td><button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#'+ value.id+'-subs" data-id="'+ value.id +'" data-init="0">Config</button></td>' +
                          '</tr>' +
                          '<tr class="dataset">' +
                          '<td colspan="2" class="subrow">' +
                          '<div style="background:#eee;" class="accordian-body collapse" id="'+ value.id+'-subs">' +
                          '<table style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="table" id="table-' + value.id + '" data-id="' + value.id + '">'+
                          '<tbody>' +
                          '</tbody>' +
                          '</table>'+
                          '<div style="margin-left:10px;" class="input-append">'+
                          '<input type="text" placeholder="Keywordgroup name">'+
                          '<button class="btn btn-create-keywordgroup" data-id="' + value.id + '"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Add</button>'+
                          '<button class="btn btn-success btn-mark-as-c" data-id="' + value.id + '"><i class="icon-white icon-check"></i> Mark as configured</button>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '</td>'+
                          '</tr>');
        });
    });
}
```

Here the function that call the function and crashes afterwards:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-mark-as-c", function(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to mark this attribute as configured?")) {
        $this = $(this)
        var id = $this.attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "/app/ajax/DataminerAjax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data    : {updateMinerAttributeState:id, state:1}
        }).success(function(json){
            if (json.status == "success") {
                // crashes here in this call of the heavy function
                getMinerAttributesByType(1);
            } else {
                alert("There was an error!");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Someone a pointer?

Comment: Have you considered paging the data?

Comment: Im not sure if it's the rendering that is such slow, so if yes sure.. I'm testing right now

Comment: Since your table is being created in the `.success()` section based on "data from php/sql", why not let php take care of the processing and display instead?

Comment: How many rows is the AJAX call returning?

Comment: About 500 rows with 4 columns

Comment: @the_pete because I use php only as a webservice

Comment: So I figured out it's the datasize, with batches of 50 datasets everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I dont have 50 rep so I cant comment yet buuuut, couldn't you bust out that chunk of HTML formatting to a PHP document, and then use the AJAX to call the PHP and return the result? Then use $table.append(result)?

Ex)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.menuItem', function()
    {   
        event.preventDefault();
        var mainCategory = $(this).attr('id').split('xx')[0];
            $.ajax({                                                          
                  url: '/php/SubMenuBar.php',  <----- Access the PHP file.       
                  data: {
                          MainCategory: mainCategory, <---- Parameters for the PHP file (declared using $_GET() in the PHP file)
                        },

                  success: function(result) <--- Result becomes the output from the PHP file
                  {
                        $table.append(result); 
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the rows to the DOM one at a time, concatenate them into a string and then add them all at once.

```
function getMinerAttributesByType(type) {
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "/app/ajax/DataminerAjax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout : 8000,
        data    : {getMinerAttributesByType:type}
    }).success(function(json){
        var $tableConfigured = $("#keywordsgroupsConf tbody");
        var $tableUnconfigured = $("#keywordsgroups tbody");
        var rowsConfigured = '', rowsUnconfigured = '';
        $.each(json, function(key, value){
            var row = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + value.name + '</td>' +
                '<td><button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#'+ value.id+'-subs" data-id="'+ value.id +'" data-init="0">Config</button></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr class="dataset">' +
                '<td colspan="2" class="subrow">' +
                '<div style="background:#eee;" class="accordian-body collapse" id="'+ value.id+'-subs">' +
                '<table style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="table" id="table-' + value.id + '" data-id="' + value.id + '">'+
                '<tbody>' +
                '</tbody>' +
                '</table>'+
                '<div style="margin-left:10px;" class="input-append">'+
                '<input type="text" placeholder="Keywordgroup name">'+
                '<button class="btn btn-create-keywordgroup" data-id="' + value.id + '"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Add</button>'+
                '<button class="btn btn-success btn-mark-as-c" data-id="' + value.id + '"><i class="icon-white icon-check"></i> Mark as configured</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</td>'+
                '</tr>';
            if (value.configured == 0) {
                rowsUnconfigured += row;
            } else {
                rowsConfigured += row;
            }
        });
        $tableConfigured.html(rowsConfigured);
        $tableUnconfigured.html(rowsUnconfigured);
    });
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but still getting a freeze. The strange thing is that on the first call it works but on the second it freezes

Comment: Is it the same number of rows the first time?